# Why isn't my update query committed to the database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following table:

```
class Schedule(Base):
    __tablename__ = "schedule_"
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": BELGARATH, "extend_existing": True})

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tour_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    round_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    player_id_p1 = Column(Integer, index=True)
    player_id_p2 = Column(Integer, index=True)
    p1_win = Column(Float)
```

Which I am trying to update with the following query:

```
    update_schedule = dal.session.query(
        Schedule.tour_id,
        Schedule.tournament_id,
        Schedule.round_id,
        Schedule.player_id_p1,
        Schedule.player_id_p2,
        Schedule.p1_win,
    )
    update_schedule = update_schedule.filter(
        Schedule.tour_id == prediction["tour_id"],
        Schedule.tournament_id == prediction["tournament_id"],
        Schedule.round_id == prediction["round_id"],
        Schedule.player_id_p1 == prediction["player_id_p1"],
        Schedule.player_id_p2 == prediction["player_id_p2"],
    )
    update_schedule.p1_win = prediction["p1_win"]
    breakpoint()
    dal.session.commit()
```

Where `prediction` is the following dictionary:

```
{'tour_id': 0, 'tournament_id': 1, 'round_id': 1, 'player_id_p1': 1, 'player_id_p2': 2, 'p1_win': 2.0}
```

The change isn't being applied to the database and I can't work out why.

If at the breakpoint I run:

```
update_schedule.p1_win
```

Then I get the result as `2.0`. However, if I look at `update_schedule` then this shows `(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, None)` and the `p1_win` change doesn't get applied to the database after the commit. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update_schedule` is a `Query` object, not a `Schedule`, so you have not made any changes to an object held in the session, or emitted an UPDATE to the DB. Python allows you to set new attributes on objects (with some exceptions), but having the new attribute set on the `Query` object has no effect. Either you meant to fetch a `Schedule` object for update, or you want to perform a bulk update using `Query.update()`. The former:

```
update_schedule = dal.session.query(Schedule).filter(
    Schedule.tour_id == prediction["tour_id"],
    Schedule.tournament_id == prediction["tournament_id"],
    Schedule.round_id == prediction["round_id"],
    Schedule.player_id_p1 == prediction["player_id_p1"],
    Schedule.player_id_p2 == prediction["player_id_p2"],
).one() # or first(), or ...
update_schedule.p1_win = prediction["p1_win"]
breakpoint()
dal.session.commit()
```

and the latter:

```
dal.session.query(Schedule).filter(
    Schedule.tour_id == prediction["tour_id"],
    Schedule.tournament_id == prediction["tournament_id"],
    Schedule.round_id == prediction["round_id"],
    Schedule.player_id_p1 == prediction["player_id_p1"],
    Schedule.player_id_p2 == prediction["player_id_p2"],
).update({
    Schedule.p1_win: prediction["p1_win"]
}, synchronize_session=False)
breakpoint()
dal.session.commit()
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Do you have a preference for the former or the latter?

Comment: Well, it depends. If the project is more ORMy, or you just happen to have the object available anyway, why not use the ORM features. But the "bulk" update does save you a SELECT, if you don't need the data for anything and just want to update.